# Почему в Git не сохраняет изменения?

Tags: git, pycharm

Произошли изменения в названиях файлов картинок. Изменения делала в Виндоус непосредственно в файлах, а не в редакторе кода. В редакторе кода изменения произошли. Add, commit, push... В Git изменений именно в названиях файлов картинок нет, остальные изменения в коде есть.

Почему? Подскажите,пожалуйста. Редактор кода PyCharm.

Comment: Напишите подробнее последовательность действий. 1 - изменила картики 2. ...

Comment: Изменила названия картинок, они изменились в редакторе тоже,потом add,потом сделала commit(были и другие изменения),потом запушила. Единственное,пришлось делать add только одного файла из измененных,только один файл посветился красным,подсказывая в редакторе,что нужно сделать add

Comment: а переименования файлов, это не изменения регистра?

Comment: Изменение регистра,с больших букв на маленькие

Comment: Git имеет параметр конфигурации, который сообщает ему, должен ли быть чувствительным к регистру или нечувствительным: core.ignorecase. Чтобы сообщить Git значение case-senstive, просто установите для этого параметра значение false:  Нашла ответ,спасибо

Comment: @ДарьяБаранова, вы можете написать это как ответ на свой вопрос 
(и возможно получить за него баллы).